# Apollo client & Absinthe - difficulty parsing errors

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, absinthe

I'm working with the @apollo/client and @absinthe/socket-apollo-link NPM packages in my React app, but I'm having some trouble parsing query and mutation errors received by `onError` in my implementation of the `useQuery` and `useMutation` hooks.

For example, here is the way I've set up a query in my component:

```
    useQuery(OperationLib.agendaQuery, {
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        onCompleted: ({ myData }) => {
            setData(myData)
            setLoading(false)
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
```

When that `onError` handler is called, the error object that is returned is logged as:

```
Error: request: [object Object]
    at new ApolloError (app.js:36358)
    at app.js:146876
    at app.js:145790
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.error (app.js:145790)
    at notifySubscription (app.js:145130)
    at onNotify (app.js:145169)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (app.js:145230)
    at app.js:58209
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I can break this response into its parts `"graphQLErrors"`, `"networkError"`, `"message"`, `"extraInfo"`, but I'm finding it difficult to get any useful info there. In particular, I'd like to be able to get something out of the `message` - but in this case, `error.message` is the string,

```
request: [object Object]
```

`typeof error.message` logs `string` so yeah I can't really do anything with this.

Maybe I could find something useful under one of the other attributes? Nope, `graphQLErrors` is an empty array, `networkError` yields the same output as I got when I logged the initial error above, and `extraInfo` is undefined.

I dug into the source code and found the method `createRequestError` - when I added a debug log here to see what the `message` was, I good some good data - I could see the message that I would think would be available somewhere in the error response:

```
var createRequestError = function createRequestError(message) {
  return new Error("request: ".concat(message));
}.bind(undefined);
```

What could be causing this issue? Is there something I need to configure in my Apollo/Absinthe initialization? I've set those up like so:

`apollo-client.js`

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client"
import absintheSocketLink from "./absinthe-socket-apollo-link"

export default new ApolloClient({
    link: absintheSocketLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
```

`absinthe-socket-apollo-link.js`

```
import * as AbsintheSocket from "@absinthe/socket"
import { createAbsintheSocketLink } from "@absinthe/socket-apollo-link"
import { Socket as PhoenixSocket } from "phoenix"

const protocol = window.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
const getToken = () => JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("token"))

let token = getToken();

const params = {
    get jwt() {
        if (!token) {
            token = getToken();
        }

        return token;
    },
};

export default createAbsintheSocketLink(
    AbsintheSocket.create(
        new PhoenixSocket(`${protocol}://${WS_API_URL}/graphql`, {
            reconnect: true,
            params: params
        })
    )
);
```

Thanks much for any insight!